# How to convert variable type "SentinelArrays" to "Arrays{Float64,n}" in julia

Tags: variables, type-conversion, julia

I am trying to optimize my Julia code by making it type-stable. Hence, I tried to declare the variable types in the function headers. But one of the variables has a type of `::SentinelArrays.ChainedVector{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}` as shown in the code snippet below.

The code example:

```
df=CSV.read("text.csv", DataFrame)

a = view(df, :, 1)      
#this has a type of ::SentinelArrays.ChainedVector{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}

b = view(df, :, 2:4)
#while type of this is ::Arrays{Float64,2}

#I would like to pass the type of the arrays in the function.
function calc(a, b::Arrays{Float64,2})
    a+b
end
```

I tried passing the `typeof(a)` in the `function` `calc(a::SentinelArrays.ChainedVector{Float64,Array{Float64,1}}, b::Arrays{Float64,2})` however, this throws an error of `no method matching`.
May I know the correct way to assign this type or maybe if can convert this to normal `Array{Float64,1}`.
Please suggest a solution to this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, I don't think annotating the types of your function's arguments will help for type stability. As a rule of thumb, I think it's best to annotate these types only when you have multiple methods and use multiple dispatch.

Answer (score 2):

You can just write `Array(a)` where `a` is your `SentinelArray` as here:

```
julia> u = SentinelArray(rand(1:8,4))
4-element SentinelVector{Int64, Int64, Missing, Vector{Int64}}:
 2
 3
 5
 3

julia> Array(u)
4-element Vector{Union{Missing, Int64}}:
 2
 3
 5
 3
```

However, normally you would just make the function signature to be something like:

```
function calc(a, b::AbstractArray{T,2}) where T
```

because this would work with both those types:

```
julia> SentinelMatrix{Int64, Int64, Missing, Matrix{Int64}} <: AbstractArray{T,2} where T
true
```